# QGIS RGB raster layer: min/max-values defined by user not working?

Tags: qgis

I tried several times to define the min/max-values for the RGB-display under `properties>style: Benutzer min/max-Werte (user min/max-values)` but it is not working. By chance it worked once but now it is not working any more. The other functions as to invert the color representation or the selection of the channel are working.

The raster file are created by the following process:

1. Scanned as an PDF
2. imported in Photoshop CS5 (modus RGB)
3. saved as (in Photoshop) tif (color profile not embedded, respectively sRGB IEC61966-2.1 not activated).

Does anybody have an idea where the problem is?